# Initialisation of an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I am trying to initialize an array of structs to zero. For some reason, I am getting the error "**expected expression**". What's wrong with my code?

```
struct mystruct {
    double a;
    double arr[2];
}

int main() {
    struct mystruct *array = (struct mystruct*)malloc(3 * sizeof(struct mystruct));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        array[i] = { 0 };
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the semicolon :-S

Comment: Oops, corrected, but no I didn't forget the semicolon in the actual code.

Comment: Consider using `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: `array[i] = {0};` --> `array[i] = (struct mystruct){0};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error. There are different ways to correct it:

- Using the C99 syntax for compound literals:

  ```
  array[i] = (struct mystruct){ 0 };
  ```
- Using a separate structure with the default values:

  ```
  struct mystruct def = { 0 };
  ...
  array[i] = def;
  ```
- Initializing each member explicitly:

  ```
  array[i].a = 0;
  array[i].arr[0] = 0;
  array[i].arr[1] = 0;
  ```
- Using `calloc()`:

  ```
  struct mystruct *array = calloc(3, sizeof(*array));
  ```

  `calloc()` initializes the memory block to all bits zero.  If your system uses IEEE representation for `double`, all bits zero corresponds to the value `0.0`. If it does not, I will give you one dollar.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate initialization is only available for, well... *initialization*:

```
struct mystruct x = {0};   // initialization
```

There's no such grammar for assignment.

But you don't need to, just use `calloc` instead of `malloc` for dynamically allocated, zeroed memory.

```
struct mystruct* array = calloc(3, sizeof(struct mystruct));
```